# Playframework Routing

Tags: java, scala, model-view-controller, playframework, routes

Ok So I am learning play framework and I understand the routes concept but the Play for Java Book is telling me to create a Products controller class like this one below

```
package controllers;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Products extends Controller {

    public static Result list() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public static Result showBlank(){
        return TODO;
    }

    public static Result show(Long ean) {
        return TODO;
    }

    public static Result save(){
        return TODO;
    }
}
```

And then it tells me to create these routes

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

GET /products/ controllers.Products.list()
GET /products/new controllers.Products.showBlank()
GET /products/:ean controllers.Products.show(ean: Long)
POST /products/ controllers.Products.save()





# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

After reviewing to make sure everything was correct in the book it gives me this error.

```
value list is not a member of controllers.Products
In C:\Users\Rijos\PlayJavaBook\conf\routes:8
5# Home page
6GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
7
8GET /products/ controllers.Products.list()
9GET /products/new controllers.Products.showBlank()
10GET /products/:ean controllers.Products.show(ean: Long)
11POST /products/ controllers.Products.save()
12
```

I know that this is a legacy way of doing this is the play framework because of the dependency injection now, but even after reading the play framework documentation I cant figure out how to use it. 
Here is my build.sbt file

```
name := """play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


fork in run := true
```

Comment: I added the build file @Tomer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add @Singlton over your controller, and remove the static declaration from your methods.

Comment: just curious what exactly does the @Singlton reference?

Comment: It will make sure Guice will instantiate this class for you, making sure it will be a singleton in your system. @CLR45

Comment: so now it takes away the error and gives me an action not found error when it tries to find the route to that specific controller and gives me the order of the paths it tried to access. @Tomer

Comment: Can you make sure you have the following line in your sbt.build: routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator @CLR45

Comment: Yea It is definitely in there

Comment: oh..amm..can you try and remove the @Singlton (my bad about that.. there is no need to use it once you extends Controller) just remove the static. if it doesn't work can you share the error message?